# How to generate a sound file inside AS3 and upload it to server?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I built a flash applet to record voice and encode it to a MP3 bytearray. By calling the upload method of a fileReference object and passing URLRequest as parameters, one can upload the file referred to a script that can process the data(e.g. php). However, FileReference.data is read-only, so I cannot figure out a way to pass the MP3 bytearray to a FileReference object, or create a file inside AS3 and load it to the FileReference object. By the way, I don't want the user to download the file and upload it manually. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Here's your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9559948/post-file-upload-using-urlrequest Use `URLRequest` without `FileReference`.

Comment: Thanks! I also find a external source to easily upload multipart/form-data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FileReference` is not used to analyze the loaded content, but to load files between a server and a computer. To do this, you can use `URLLoader` class. Listening the events is directly made by the URLLoader object.

```
var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
loader.load(new URLRequest("myFile"));
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadingFinished);
```

To access the data, we use `data`'s property of the URLLoader object :

```
function loadingFinished(e:Event):void {
    trace(e.currentTarget.data);
}
```